# when deploying to heroku, it doesnt see my jar files or maven dependency in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, servlets, heroku

I am trying to deploy my app using heroku website, but it does not see any maven dependency like `HttpServlet` `although` I have it in my `pom.xml` AND it doesn't see `Gson.jar` although its in the lib directory. I have added `webapp-runner` plugin but nothing happened.
This is the error that I got. your help is appreciated. Thanks all.

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
       [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDealsServlet.java:[6,21] package javax.servlet does not exist
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDealsServlet.java:[7,26] package javax.servlet.http does not exist
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDealsServlet.java:[8,26] package javax.servlet.http does not exist
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDealsServlet.java:[9,26] package javax.servlet.http does not exist
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDealsServlet.java:[11,48] package com.sun.javafx.collections.MappingChange does not exist
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDealsServlet.java:[13,40] cannot find symbol
         symbol: class HttpServlet
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDealsServlet.java:[15,30] cannot find symbol
         symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
         location: class hotels.HotelDealsServlet
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDealsServlet.java:[15,54] cannot find symbol
         symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
         location: class hotels.HotelDealsServlet
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDealsServlet.java:[15,87] cannot find symbol
         symbol:   class ServletException
         location: class hotels.HotelDealsServlet
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDealsServlet.java:[24,64] cannot find symbol
         symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
         location: class hotels.HotelDealsServlet
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDeals.java:[14,23] package com.google.gson does not exist
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDeals.java:[15,48] package com.sun.javafx.collections.MappingChange does not exist
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/Deals.java:[6,48] package com.sun.javafx.collections.MappingChange does not exist
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDealsServlet.java:[14,9] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDeals.java:[26,38] cannot find symbol
         symbol:   class Gson
         location: class hotels.HotelDeals
       [INFO] 15 errors 
       [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time: 9.514 s
       [INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-09T16:25:19+00:00
       [INFO] Final Memory: 19M/177M
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project hotels: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDealsServlet.java:[6,21] package javax.servlet does not exist
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDealsServlet.java:[7,26] package javax.servlet.http does not exist
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDealsServlet.java:[8,26] package javax.servlet.http does not exist
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDealsServlet.java:[9,26] package javax.servlet.http does not exist
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDealsServlet.java:[11,48] package com.sun.javafx.collections.MappingChange does not exist
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDealsServlet.java:[13,40] cannot find symbol
       [ERROR] symbol: class HttpServlet
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDealsServlet.java:[15,30] cannot find symbol
       [ERROR] symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
       [ERROR] location: class hotels.HotelDealsServlet
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDealsServlet.java:[15,54] cannot find symbol
       [ERROR] symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
       [ERROR] location: class hotels.HotelDealsServlet
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDealsServlet.java:[15,87] cannot find symbol
       [ERROR] symbol:   class ServletException
       [ERROR] location: class hotels.HotelDealsServlet
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDealsServlet.java:[24,64] cannot find symbol
       [ERROR] symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
       [ERROR] location: class hotels.HotelDealsServlet
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDeals.java:[14,23] package com.google.gson does not exist
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDeals.java:[15,48] package com.sun.javafx.collections.MappingChange does not exist
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/Deals.java:[6,48] package com.sun.javafx.collections.MappingChange does not exist
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDealsServlet.java:[14,9] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_d6140010f65ec320b1605ee2b8276832/khalidCS-deals-hotel-fa63bfd/src/main/java/hotels/HotelDeals.java:[26,38] cannot find symbol
       [ERROR] symbol:   class Gson
       [ERROR] location: class hotels.HotelDeals
       [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
       [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
       [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
 !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
       We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
       please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
 !     Push failed
```

Adding POM posted in the answer section by OP

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.khalid.hotels</groupId>
    <artifactId>hotels</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>embeddedTomcatSample Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <tomcat.version>8.5.23</tomcat.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>8.0.30.2</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                <version>7.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: This is the github project that I am trying to deploy https://github.com/khalidCS/deals-hotel

Comment: Please add pom.xml, as I am not able to access github from my country.

Comment: kindly view in the comment

Comment: I have added POM in the original post, where it belongs. Please delete your post in answer section. I have given updated POM in the answer section. Please try that and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the updated POM below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.khalid.hotels</groupId>
    <artifactId>hotels</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>embeddedTomcatSample Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <tomcat.version>8.5.23</tomcat.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>8.0.30.2</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                <version>7.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</project>
```